# How to remove my toggle animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I am using WordPress Theme "Divi" in my site. I am facing some problem in toggle when click on close toggle its opening very slowly I want to remove its slow animation I want when click on toggle it should appear normally not slowly How can I do this ?

This is the page where I am facing this problem.
http://justgasit.net/revamp/about-us/

Comment: what about sharing some code too?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you would have gotten an answer much more quickly had you posted some code.

In your `custom.min.js` file search for instances of (omit the ellipsis [...] in your find and replace)

```
$content.slideToggle(700,function() ...
```

You can change these to

```
$content.toggle(0,function()  ...
```

It may help to un-minify that file for easier editing, however, be sure to minify it back once you are done editing to keep the file size down in production.

Comment: I did Legen what you told me but there is still some animation . I want to remove its animation completely just need normal accordion. Please tell me